# PhpStorm built-in server http/2 support

Tags: phpstorm, http2

Is it possible to enable http/2 support in PhpStorm PHP Built-in Web Server? If not, is it possible to use one of the other server options to run PHP server (Laravel to be precise) with http/2 support?

I'm talking about those:

[image]

Comment: The [PHP Built-in Web Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) is a functionality provided by PHP CLI since version 5.4. Afaik, it doesn't provide HTTP/2 support (because its purpose is to help developers, it is not a production-ready feature). The PHP Built-in Web Server is not related to PhpStorm in any way.

Comment: @axiac True. But at the same time -- PhpStorm has own simple built-in web server -- and OP may got confused which one is which.

Comment: @Linek In any case -- none of the above will provide HTTP2 -- you need proper Apache or nginx for that. PhpStorm's own built-in web server is used when no Deployment server is configured and uses URLs like `localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME/path/to/file.html`. Install proper web server with HTTP2 support; define deployment entry (if needed) and mark it as Default for this project -- URL from there will be used when using "Open in Browser" actions. If you do not need to use such actions  -- such deployment entry is optional/not needed.

Comment: P.S. If installing Apache/nginx on local computer is not an option -- consider Vagrant (Homestead) or any other VM (custom image) .. or some Docker container perhaps (e.g. https://github.com/laradock/laradock or similar).... https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/general/automating-setup-local-developer-machine/

Comment: @aziac That I didn't know, thanks for clarifying.